# Search text file and insert line

Tags: python, file-io

What I want to do is (using the text below as an example), search for the string “Text2” in a text file, and then insert a line (“Inserted Text”) two lines after "Text 2". “Text 2” could be on any line in the text file but I know it will appear once within the text file.

So here’s the original file:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
Text4
```

And here’s what I want:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
Inserted Text
Text 4
```

So I already know how to add text above a line using the code below.

```
for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=1,backup='.bak'):
    if line.startswith('Text 4'):
        print "Inserted Text"
        print line,
    else:
        print line,
```

But I just don't know how to add something two lines after the text I'm searching for in the file.

Comment: the print line and else clause are redundant, just print the line after you exit the if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the file contents into a list, it would be easier to manipulate:

```
searchline = 'Text4'
lines = f.readlines() # f being the file handle
i = lines.index(searchline) # Make sure searchline is actually in the file
```

Now `i` contains the index of the line `Text4`. You can use that and `list.insert(i,x)` to insert before:

```
lines.insert(i, 'Random text to insert')
```

Or after:

```
lines.insert(i+1, 'Different random text')
```

Or three lines after:

```
lines.insert(i+3, 'Last example text')
```

Just make sure to include error handling for `IndexError`s and you can do with that whatever you want.

Comment: This works for an exact match. Is there anything similar for line starting with string or containing string?

Comment: I'm not aware of a pretty, concise way to do it, although my Python is a bit rusty these days. But as far as I know you'll have to iterate the lines to find the right index, similar to @Boaan's solution.

Answer (score 3):

The quick-n-dirty way would be something like that

```
before=-1
for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=1,backup='.bak'):
    if line.startswith('Text 2'):
        before = 2
    if before == 0
        print "Inserted Text"
    if before > -1
        before = before - 1
    print line,
```

Comment: And for handling the line starts with category. Use `if 'Text 2' in line:` to find a line containing a string

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
f = open("file.txt","rw")
lines = f.readlines()
for i in range(len(lines)):
     if lines[i].startswith("Text2"):
            lines.insert(i+3,"Inserted text") #Before the line three lines after this, i.e. 2 lines later.

print "\n".join(lines)
```

Comment: How to write this string, into this file?