# Insert a line into the middle of a text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to insert a line into the middle of a text file in Python, so I tried

```
with open(erroredFilepath, 'r+t') as erroredFile:
    fileContents = erroredFile.read()

    if 'insert_here' in fileContents:
        insertString.join(fileContents.rsplit('insert_here'))
        erroredFile.truncate()
        erroredFile.write(insertString)
```

However, `insertString` got written at the end of the file. Why?

---

As an aside, I tried to simply things, by just using strings, instead of files.

```
'123456789'.join('qwertyuiop'.split('y'))
```

gives

```
'qwert123456789uiop'
```

what happened to the 'y' ?

Comment: To answer the latter question: the 'y' isn't included in the resulting array. It may be easier to see if you have the string "I like to play" and split it by a single space, the array will contain "I", "like", "to", and "play", but without spaces.

Comment: Is 'the middle' a separate line? Please provide a sample input and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write in the middle of the file use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(erroredFilepath, inplace=True):
    print("something", end ="")
```

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput)

> if the keyword argument `inplace=True` is passed to `fileinput.input()` or to the `FileInput` constructor, the file is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it will be replaced silently).

Whatever you `print` will go in the file. So you have to read and `print` every line and modify whichever you want to replace. Also, when `print`ing existing lines, use `end=""` as it will prevent `print` from adding an extra newline.

Comment: That looks like the way (and it'S Pythonic). I will test it & get back. Btw, for v3.4, the dox are at https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fileinput.html (alter the URL for other versions)

Comment: I may also read the file contents into a list & manipulate that, as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147836/search-text-file-and-insert-line

Comment: @Mawg you can do whtever you want with data but the new file will have only what you `print`.If you dont `print` new file will be empty.

Comment: it would be `print("something", end ="")` for python3

Answer (score 2):

Although OS-level details of files vary, in general, when you have a file open in `r+` mode and do some read or write operation, the "current position" is left after the last read or write.

When you did:

```
fileContents = erroredFile.read()
```

the stream `erroredFile` was read to the end, so the current position is now "at the end".

The truncate function defaults to using the current position as the size to which to truncate.  Assume the file is 100 bytes long, so that the current position "at the end" is byte 100.  Then:

```
erroredFile.truncate()
```

means "make the file 100 bytes long"—which it already is.

The current position remains at the end of the file, so the subsequent `write` appends.

Presumably you wanted to seek back to the beginning of the file, and/or use `truncate(0)` (note that just `truncate(0)` will, at least on Unix-like systems, leave the seek position at the end of the file so that the next `write` leaves a hole where the original data used to be). You could also be slightly more clever: if you're inserting, just overwrite-and-extend in place (no `truncate` is required at all).

(Joel Hinz already answered the second question, I see.)

Comment: I thought also about tell() and seek()

Answer (score 1):

test.txt

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

## 1. Read into a list then overwrite

```py
def match_then_insert(filename, match, content):
    lines = open(filename).read().splitlines()
    index = lines.index(match)
    lines.insert(index, content)
    open(filename, mode='w').write('\n'.join(lines))


match_then_insert('test.txt', match='c', content='123')
```

Result

```
a
b
123
c
d
e
```

## 2. [FileInput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput)

```py
from fileinput import FileInput


def match_then_insert(filename, match, content):
    for line in FileInput(filename, inplace=True):
        if match in line:
            line = content + '\n' + line
        print(line, end='')  # Redirect to the original file


match_then_insert('test.txt', match='c', content='123')
```

## 3. [seek](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)

```py
def match_then_insert(filename, match, content):
    with open(filename, mode='rb+') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                line = f.readline()
            except IndexError:
                break
            line_str = line.decode().splitlines()[0]
            if line_str == match:
                f.seek(-len(line), 1)
                rest = f.read()
                f.seek(-len(rest), 1)
                f.truncate()
                content = content + '\n'
                f.write(content.encode())
                f.write(rest)
                break


match_then_insert('test.txt', match='c', content='123')
```

## Compare

| Method | Time/s |
| --- | --- |
| Read into a list then overwrite | 54.42 |
| FileInput | 121.59 |
| seek | 3.53 |

```py
from timeit import timeit
from fileinput import FileInput


def init_txt():
    open('test.txt', mode='w').write('\n'.join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']))


def f1(filename='test.txt', match='c', content='123'):
    lines = open(filename).read().splitlines()
    index = lines.index(match)
    lines.insert(index, content)
    open(filename, mode='w').write('\n'.join(lines))


def f2(filename='test.txt', match='c', content='123'):
    for line in FileInput(filename, inplace=True):
        if match in line:
            line = content + '\n' + line
        print(line, end='')


def f3(filename='test.txt', match='c', content='123'):
    with open(filename, mode='rb+') as f:
        while True:
            try:
                line = f.readline()
            except IndexError:
                break
            line_str = line.decode().splitlines()[0]
            if line_str == match:
                f.seek(-len(line), 1)
                rest = f.read()
                f.seek(-len(rest), 1)
                f.truncate()
                content = content + '\n'
                f.write(content.encode())
                f.write(rest)
                break


init_txt()
print(timeit(f1, number=1000))
init_txt()
print(timeit(f2, number=1000))
init_txt()
print(timeit(f3, number=1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not try a two steps solution? At first, you read and fix the string, at the second step, you rewrite the file. Probably it's not the most efficient algorithm, but I think it works.

```
with open(erroredFilepath, 'r') as erroredFile:
    fileContents = erroredFile.read()   
    fileContents.replace('insert_here', 'insert_string')

with open(erroredFilePath, 'w') as fixingFile:
    fixingFile.write(fileContents)
```

Answer (score -1):

Not a Python answer but it may widen your horizon. Use `sed`:

```
$ cat input.txt 
foo
bar
baz
INSERT HERE
qux
quux

$ sed '/INSERT HERE/anew stuff' < input.txt
foo
bar
baz
INSERT HERE
new stuff
qux
quux
```

The command `a` will append the text on a new line. If you want to insert the text *before* the match, use the command `i`:

```
$ sed '/INSERT HERE/inew stuff' < input.txt
foo
bar
baz
new stuff
INSERT HERE
qux
quux
```